# select data before & after midnight

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a dashboard that reports production for each hour of a shift. The dashboard has fixed slots for each hour of the shift.

- When the shift is 7am to 7pm all is fine.
- When the shift is 7pm to 7am then I have an issue.
- 7pm to 8pm is fine
- 8pm to 9pm is fine
- 9pm to 10pm is fine
- 10pm to 11pm is fine
- 11pm to 12pm is fine
- 12pm to 1am is an issue - The issue is that when you log on to the dashboard at 7pm I pick up the production for today’s production from midnight to 1am.
  How can I code my sql to ignore data from midnight to 1am before midnight and select it after midnight?

Here is the SQL that i am using

```
select date_time_created,
       ith.quantity
From   ifsapp.inventory_transaction_hist2 ith
where  TRANSACTION_CODE = 'OOREC'
and    upper(ifsapp.Inventory_Part_API.Get_Unit_Meas('WW001',PART_NO) ) =upper( 'CS' )
and    date_time_created -1 - 60*60*7/86400 >= to_date(to_char(sysdate -1,'DD/MM/YYYY') || ' 19:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')- 60*60*7/86400
and    date_time_created - 60*60*7/86400 <= to_date(to_char(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY') || ' 19:59:59','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')- 60*60*7/86400
and    userid='3520'
```

thanks

Comment: I don't understand your query. You are doing a lot of time math, but as you add or subtract the same thing left and right, it's all void. You end up with WHERE date_time_created = today at 19:xx:xx. But where are the shift times you are taking about? I thought your table would contain something like start_shift and end_shift. Where is that "for each hour" in your query? Please show sample data and expected results.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `How can I code my sql to ignore data from midnight to 1am before midnight and select it after midnight?`. Can you provide some sample input data, along with the output you're expecting to see?

Comment: When you turn a date to a character string, manipulate the string, and then turn it back into a date, you're almost certainly doing something wrong. Manipulate dates using date functions and algebra only ... e.g. Trunc(sysdate) + 7/24

Answer (score 0):

7pm to 7am:

```
date_time_created between to_date( to_char(sysdate-1, 'ddmmyyyy') || '19:00:00', 'ddmmyyhh24:mi:ss')
                    AND   to_date( to_char(sysdate, 'ddmmyyyy')   || '07:00:00', 'ddmmyyhh24:mi:ss')
```

12pm to 1am:

```
date_time_created between to_date( to_char(sysdate-1, 'ddmmyyyy') || '12:00:00', 'ddmmyyhh24:mi:ss')
                    AND   to_date( to_char(sysdate, 'ddmmyyyy')   || '01:00:00', 'ddmmyyhh24:mi:ss')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after, but if you're wanting to see the results of the current shift, hopefully this example will help you work out what you need to do:

```
WITH dates AS (SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 5.1/24 + LEVEL/24 dt
               FROM   dual
               CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 36)
-- end of generating some data for the following query to run against
SELECT dt,
       CASE WHEN to_number(to_char(dt - 7/24, 'hh24')) < 12 THEN '7am-7pm'
            ELSE '7pm-7am'
       END shift
FROM   dates
WHERE  dt >= CASE WHEN to_number(to_char(SYSDATE - 7/24, 'hh24')) < 12 THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE -7/24) + 7/24
                  ELSE TRUNC(SYSDATE -7/24) + 19/24
             END
AND    dt < CASE WHEN to_number(to_char(SYSDATE - 7/24, 'hh24')) < 12 THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE -7/24) + 19/24
                 ELSE TRUNC(SYSDATE -7/24) + 31/24
            END;

DT                  SHIFT
------------------- -------
06/10/2016 07:06:00 7am-7pm
06/10/2016 08:06:00 7am-7pm
06/10/2016 09:06:00 7am-7pm
06/10/2016 10:06:00 7am-7pm
06/10/2016 11:06:00 7am-7pm
06/10/2016 12:06:00 7am-7pm
06/10/2016 13:06:00 7am-7pm
06/10/2016 14:06:00 7am-7pm
06/10/2016 15:06:00 7am-7pm
06/10/2016 16:06:00 7am-7pm
06/10/2016 17:06:00 7am-7pm
06/10/2016 18:06:00 7am-7pm
```

And just to prove that for different sysdates, the report would generated, I've set up the query to use different "sysdts" to mimic being run at different times in the day:

```
WITH dates AS (SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 5.1/24 + LEVEL/24 dt
               FROM   dual
               CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 36),
-- end of generating some data for the main query to run against
 sys_dates AS (SELECT to_date('06/10/2016 20:10:23', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') sysdt FROM dual UNION ALL
               SELECT to_date('06/10/2016 13:10:23', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') sysdt FROM dual UNION ALL
               SELECT to_date('07/10/2016 01:10:23', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') sysdt FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking different sysdates that the report could be run against
-- - for testing purposes only
SELECT sd.sysdt run_time_of_report,
       d.dt,
       CASE WHEN to_number(to_char(d.dt - 7/24, 'hh24')) < 12 THEN '7am-7pm'
            ELSE '7pm-7am'
       END shift
FROM   dates d
       CROSS JOIN sys_dates sd
WHERE  d.dt >= CASE WHEN to_number(to_char(sd.sysdt - 7/24, 'hh24')) < 12 THEN TRUNC(sd.sysdt -7/24) + 7/24
                    ELSE TRUNC(sd.sysdt -7/24) + 19/24
               END
AND    d.dt < CASE WHEN to_number(to_char(sd.sysdt - 7/24, 'hh24')) < 12 THEN TRUNC(sd.sysdt -7/24) + 19/24
                   ELSE TRUNC(sd.sysdt -7/24) + 31/24
              END
ORDER BY sd.sysdt, d.dt;

RUN_TIME_OF_REPORT  DT                  SHIFT
------------------- ------------------- -------
06/10/2016 13:10:23 06/10/2016 07:06:00 7am-7pm
06/10/2016 13:10:23 06/10/2016 08:06:00 7am-7pm
06/10/2016 13:10:23 06/10/2016 09:06:00 7am-7pm
06/10/2016 13:10:23 06/10/2016 10:06:00 7am-7pm
06/10/2016 13:10:23 06/10/2016 11:06:00 7am-7pm
06/10/2016 13:10:23 06/10/2016 12:06:00 7am-7pm
06/10/2016 13:10:23 06/10/2016 13:06:00 7am-7pm
06/10/2016 13:10:23 06/10/2016 14:06:00 7am-7pm
06/10/2016 13:10:23 06/10/2016 15:06:00 7am-7pm
06/10/2016 13:10:23 06/10/2016 16:06:00 7am-7pm
06/10/2016 13:10:23 06/10/2016 17:06:00 7am-7pm
06/10/2016 13:10:23 06/10/2016 18:06:00 7am-7pm
--
06/10/2016 20:10:23 06/10/2016 19:06:00 7pm-7am
06/10/2016 20:10:23 06/10/2016 20:06:00 7pm-7am
06/10/2016 20:10:23 06/10/2016 21:06:00 7pm-7am
06/10/2016 20:10:23 06/10/2016 22:06:00 7pm-7am
06/10/2016 20:10:23 06/10/2016 23:06:00 7pm-7am
06/10/2016 20:10:23 07/10/2016 00:06:00 7pm-7am
06/10/2016 20:10:23 07/10/2016 01:06:00 7pm-7am
06/10/2016 20:10:23 07/10/2016 02:06:00 7pm-7am
06/10/2016 20:10:23 07/10/2016 03:06:00 7pm-7am
06/10/2016 20:10:23 07/10/2016 04:06:00 7pm-7am
06/10/2016 20:10:23 07/10/2016 05:06:00 7pm-7am
06/10/2016 20:10:23 07/10/2016 06:06:00 7pm-7am
-- 
07/10/2016 01:10:23 06/10/2016 19:06:00 7pm-7am
07/10/2016 01:10:23 06/10/2016 20:06:00 7pm-7am
07/10/2016 01:10:23 06/10/2016 21:06:00 7pm-7am
07/10/2016 01:10:23 06/10/2016 22:06:00 7pm-7am
07/10/2016 01:10:23 06/10/2016 23:06:00 7pm-7am
07/10/2016 01:10:23 07/10/2016 00:06:00 7pm-7am
07/10/2016 01:10:23 07/10/2016 01:06:00 7pm-7am
07/10/2016 01:10:23 07/10/2016 02:06:00 7pm-7am
07/10/2016 01:10:23 07/10/2016 03:06:00 7pm-7am
07/10/2016 01:10:23 07/10/2016 04:06:00 7pm-7am
07/10/2016 01:10:23 07/10/2016 05:06:00 7pm-7am
07/10/2016 01:10:23 07/10/2016 06:06:00 7pm-7am
```

You can see that the report as at 06/10/2016 20:10:23 and 07/10/2016 01:10:23 pulls back the same data for the 7pm-7am shift.